# Creating scenarios using Excel Solver & Data Tables with some contraints

Tags: excel, datatables, solver

I am trying to create scenarios using Data Table where i can get 1000 scenarios the weights of variables changing with some constraint.

Sum of weight for 6 variables should be 1, and each weight has to lie within the range as given in table below

constraint 1 -> A+B+C+D+E+F = 100

Constraint 2 -> individual variable weights can vary between these values
[image]

I have tried using RANDARRAY() function with the solver tool in excel, and added the above constraint but it only gives me 1 set of solution.  Then the cells changes to values.

What i need is set of 1000 solutions/iteration in a form of data table